# Force touch the app icon when app closed from task manager

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

while using quick actions of 3D Touch it works good but while app is terminated first time force touch the app icon it open home screen but the other times it open the right screen.
why this happen and how I can test the app while it is terminated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the method `application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)` you can use the launchOptions argument to detect whether user is launching the app by pressing shortcut item key or not.

```
if launchOptions != nil {
        if let userInfo = launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey] {
            //Handled the implementation here
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't debug app while it is launched after terminated

Comment: Add two alert view one is inside the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method and another one in "performActionForShortcutItem" and then check which alert view is called first.

Comment: You can add a NSLog and see the log in device console.

Comment: I got it your solution makes me know that performActionForShortcutItem not called after app is terminated . it solved when I return yes in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method if launch options contains UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey